# How to pass differently-typed composable functions up front in type-safe way?

Tags: python, functional-programming, type-hinting, mypy, first-class-functions

I have a `ValuePropagator`:

```
V = TypeVar("V")

class ValuePropagator(ABC, Generic[V]):
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, funcs: Sequence[Callable[[V], V]], value: V) -> V:
        pass
```

A sample implementation propagates `value` eagerly, calling all of `funcs` on each invocation of `get`:

```
class EagerValuePropagator(ValuePropagator[V], Generic[V]):
    def get(self, funcs: Sequence[Callable[[V], V]], value: V) -> V:
        for func in funcs:
            value = func(value)
            
        return value
```

I also have other implementations that do various levels of caching. One caches the final value after applying all `funcs`, the other caches intermediate value after applying each `func`. All is good so far.

My new use case requires intermediate types to be different than `V`. For example, I may receive 2 `funcs`: a `Callable[[V1], V2]` and `Callable[[V2], V3]`. My `get` method would then need to return `V3`, given a `V1`.

My first effort was to compose these `funcs` beforehand into one `Callable[[V1], V3]`. But many implementations of `ValuePropagator` require access to the separated `funcs` for caching strategies, and passing a composed `Callable` would take away this granularity.

How can I change `ValuePropagator` to support multiple types between these `funcs`, while keeping type safety? Couple specifications:

- Passing `Callable[[V1], V2]` and `Callable[[V1], V3]` would need to fail type checking because the output of the first callable is of a different type than the input of the second, causing the piping to fail.
- I need to be able to receive all the functions up front such that parts of my cumulative operation can remain cached, while others remain uncached.

As a last resort, I can keep this logic untyped using `Any`, but would appreciate any ideas to try beforehand.

Comment: My experience has been that Python's type system is not completely mature.  It's been designed to handle the most common cases, but fails miserably when having to deal with anything beyond the most simple functions-as-arguments or functions-as-return-values.   I will follow this thread in case someone has better answers.

Comment: Switching to Haskell-like syntax for brevity, I'm not sure how you would statically specify the type of `[f, g, h]` such that `f . g . h :: a -> d` is defined. `f :: c -> d` and `h :: a -> b` don't have anything in common, other than the existence of `g :: b -> c` in the list to act as the link between them. You need to consider not just the type(s) of functions, but the order in which they appear.

Comment: That's a [thrist](https://github.com/ggreif/omega/blob/master/doc/Thrist-draft-2011-11-20.pdf). I guess it makes Python's mind explode.